# How to inject a model list in to my controller so i can use the list data and add it to a ViewBag to be displayd on my apge in ASP.Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am using a submit button with a post function to send the quantity and product to a list item using a Model (Cart. cs). How do I get that data (inject) to the controller so I can use the quantity total of all orders to add to a ViewBag to be displayed in different parts of the site?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace MyStore.Models
{
    public class Cart
    {
        public List<CartLine> Lines { get; set; } = new List<CartLine>();
        public virtual void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
        {
            CartLine line = Lines
            .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
            .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                Lines.Add(new CartLine
                {
                    Product = product,
                    Quantity = quantity
                });
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        } 
        public virtual void RemoveLine(Product product) =>
        Lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        public decimal ComputeTotalValue() =>
        Lines.Sum(e => e.Product.Price * e.Quantity);


        public virtual void Clear() => Lines.Clear();
    }
    public class CartLine
    {
        public int CartLineID { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to bind data(List) from your web page(.chstml/html) into ViewBag?

Comment: I guess that's what I am after. I want to use the total quantity of items in the car to be displayed on various parts of the page. Currently, I have a ViewBag where I can set a number manually and it sends it to the pages where I like but now I want it to use the total quantity as described above.

Comment: Can you share the structure of CartLine?So that we can give you a sample.

Comment: just added the cart.cs model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use session,so that you can keep the list in different actions.Check session is null or not in your action.If session is not null,set Lines with  session.And after add data to lines,set session with the updated Lines.Here is a demo:

configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    
            ...

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
           
        }
```

controller:

```
public List<CartLine> Lines { get; set; } = new List<CartLine>();
        public virtual void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lines")))
            {
                Lines=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartLine>>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lines"));
            }
            CartLine line = Lines
            .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
            .FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
            {
                Lines.Add(new CartLine
                {
                    Product = product,
                    Quantity = quantity
                });
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Lines", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lines));
        } 
        public virtual void RemoveLine(Product product){
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lines")))
                {
                    Lines=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartLine>>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lines"));
                }
            Lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("Lines", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Lines));
        }
        
        public decimal ComputeTotalValue(){
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lines")))
                {
                    Lines=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CartLine>>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Lines"));
                }
             Lines.Sum(e => e.Product.Price * e.Quantity);
        }
```